# I want to place my second row div just below the first row div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two rows in which in first row I have three div's, third div is having great height. Where as in second row I have one single div.I just want to place my second row div just below the first row div without using margin top in negative and sequence should be same instead of taking parent div of 1,2 and 4th div.Thank you in advance.

```css
div{
 float: left;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:40%;padding:40px;background-color:pink;"> 
1
</div>

<div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:black;">
2
</div>

<div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:green; height:500px;">
3
</div>
<div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:blue;">
4
</div>
```

Comment: @Paulie_D Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you use jquery on your page? Not sure what you're trying to achieve but that is just a weird structure for your divs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do that just with css and maintaining the order of the div. Something similar would be this: http://w3bits.com/labs/css-masonry/  but the order is in columns, not rows

Answer (score 0):

yahh just add clear both to those div that you want to put down.
like

```
<div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:black;clear: both;">2</div>
```

Comment: @Alexscended Please check the above comment. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Jainam lease check the above comment. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try a different structure in your divs if you want to achieve that, if I understand correct..

Create one row with cascading divs for the left-pane and one row for the right-page (third div)

```
<div class="left-pane">
    <div style="width:40%;padding:40px;background-color:pink;">1</div>
    <div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:black;">2</div>
    <div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:blue;">4</div>
</div>
<div class="right-pane">
    <div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:green; height:500px;">3</div>
</div>
```

Let me know if this worked out for you. I'll be happy to help.

Comment: As i have said I don't want to have any parent div of div 1,2,4. Thank you so much though.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution by my own. Thank you guys for your efforts.

```css
div{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:40%;padding:40px;background-color:pink; float:left;"> 
1
</div>

<div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:black;float:left;">
2
</div>

<div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:green; height:500px;float:right;">
3
</div>
<div style="width:20%;padding:40px;background-color:blue;float:left;">
4
</div>
```